# What's the best way to modify a library function in c++?

Tags: c++

What's the best way if I want to make sure that every parameter that's passed to the `setX()` method is a positive number?

For example:

```
 a.setX(32); // I don't need to worry about if 32 is less than 0
 if(a.getY()-64 > 0)
 {
     b.setX(a.getY()-64); // But I have to check if a variable will be less than 0
 }
```

Can I make a few changes in the `setX()` method by adding an if statement there? But modifying a function in a third-party library is not a good idea, is it? Is there a way to achieve this without touching the library?

Of course I can manually make sure that the argument is a positive value every time I call this function. But this sounds even worse. I'll probably call this function very frequently and I can't just do something to check the value every time before I call this function. What's the best way then?

Comment: Add an assert to the function. "modifying a function in a third-party library is not a good idea, is it?" depends. Adding this assert won't (shouldn't) change its behaviour, so if others use your code and their own copy of the original library it will still work. But at least you get to debug your logic.

Comment: you can build a wrapper function and pass it an absolute value like `setx(abs(value))`

Comment: @w.b So you are suggesting bad input should be passed through without error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply create your own function and make sure you only call this one and never the original one:

```
inline void MySetX( TheClass& a, int value )
{
    if ( value >= 0 )
    {
         a.setX( value );
    }
    else
    {
         // Do your error handling, throw exception, assert, or whatever
    }
}
```

Then, replace all your `a.setX( i )` by `MySetX( a, i )`

Comment: I agree. Don't change the library, create an interface wrapper to the library. In addition to allowing you to validate the inputs, this will help insulate your code from changes in new versions of the library. See also the [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Comment: (OP:) This sounds like a good solution, but I'll have to re-write everything that's already been written as "a.setX" and I don't actually know any good refactoring tool to change every "a.setX(i)" to "MySetX(a, i)". Can I create a subclass that extends the TheClass? So that I can keep my source code consistent with the library? And if so, how to?

Comment: Yes you can, but you'll then have to change every place where TheClass objects are created. If you're using Visual Studio, the "replace in file" tool is great and can be used to replace `<pattern1>.setX( <pattern2> )` by `MySetX( <pattern1>, <pattern2> )`

Comment: OK, I wrote a subclass to extend TheClass and it works fine. So I decided to use #define directive to change when objects get created. I  tried replacing a = TheClass::create(); with a = (TheClass*)TheSubclass::create(); and it works well, but #define TheClass::create (TheClass*)TheSubclass::create doesn't work. Why?

Comment: You cannot use :: in macro names. You moved your problem from replacing all `setX` by `MySetX` to replacing all `TheClass` creation by `TheSubclass` creation....Moreover, if `setX` was not declared `virtual`, note that calling `setX` on a `TheClass*` pointer (even if created as a `TheSubclass` object), won't call `TheSubclass::setX` function, it will execute `TheClass::setX`....